# Как в sqlplus направить вывод результата запроса в файл?

Tags: oracle, sql

Как в sqlplus направить вывод результата запроса в файл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в вашем скрипте, запускаемом из консоли SQLPlus, перед началом перенаправления в файл

```
spool имя-файла;
```

после завершения перенаправления

```
spool off
```

Answer (score 3):

Обычно в скрипте уже включено перенаправление, например для логгирования. Если запрос должен быть выведен в другой файл, то можно переключить перенапавление на время выполнения запроса:

```
define mylog='logfile.log'
spool &mylog
prompt ## creating csv
set colsep ';' termout off
spool data.csv
-- результат пишется в csv файл без вывода в терминал
select 1 id, 'text 1' col1, 'text 2' col2 from dual;
spool &mylog append
-- отсюда пишется в старый лог файл и терминал
set termout on
prompt ## csv created
spool off

SQL> host more data.csv

        ID;COL1  ;COL2
----------;------;------
         1;text 1;text 2
```